# Remove hairline border in elements in chrome mobile mode

Tags: html, css, border

I'm having an issue where chrome and other major browsers are adding a hairline border around elements on mobile devices. **Note:** *It only happens on mobile devices.*

https://codepen.io/AlphaT7/pen/bMoQpz

You can see it if you use mobile mode in chrome dev tools, or by just using a mobile device.

Setting `border: 0;` does not fix it. How do I remove these element outlines?

[image]

Comment: I cannot replicate this using Chrome mobile or via Chrome dev tools. Can you provide a screenshot of the hairline border?

Comment: sure, have done

Comment: Have you ever found a good solution? I am struggling with this one as well.

Comment: no, unfortunately not; I think I ended up going with a different design because of this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to ur css

```
.checkout-progress .progress-bar li .triangle2 {
    border-left-color: white;
    left: -1px; //change this value from 0 to -1px
}
```

Its not a border, it a part of the **a tag** which is visible from behind the **triangle2**

Setting the value of `left` from 0 to -1 will push the traingle2 more  to the left, thus hiding the **a tag** background visible

Also adjusted the height of traingle by setting the border width to 15px

```css
.checkout-progress {
  clear: both;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 70px auto;
}

.checkout-progress .progress-bar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.checkout-progress .progress-bar li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #eee;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-right: 13px;
}

.checkout-progress .progress-bar li .triangle,
.checkout-progress .progress-bar li .triangle2 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -10px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #eee;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  z-index: 1;
}

.checkout-progress .progress-bar li .triangle2 {
  border-left-color: white;
  left: -1px;
}

.checkout-progress .progress-bar li:first-child {
  border: 0;
}

.checkout-progress .progress-bar li.current-step {
  background: green;
}

.checkout-progress .progress-bar li.current-step .triangle {
  border-left: 10px solid green;
}

.checkout-progress .progress-bar li.current-step a {
  color: white;
}

.checkout-progress .progress-bar li.current-step a .step-number {
  border-color: white;
}

.checkout-progress .progress-bar li.visited-step {
  background: #bbb;
}

.checkout-progress .progress-bar li.visited-step .triangle {
  border-left: 10px solid #bbb;
}

.checkout-progress .progress-bar li a {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 31px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 30px;
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: default;
}

.checkout-progress .progress-bar li a em {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: none;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkout-progress">
  <ul class="progress-bar">
    <li class="checkout-step1 visited-step">
      <span class="triangle2"></span>
      <a href="#"><em>1</em>First Step</a>
      <span class="triangle after"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="checkout-step2 current-step">
      <span class="triangle2"></span>
      <a href="#"><em>2</em>Second Step</a>
      <span class="triangle"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="checkout-step3">
      <span class="triangle2"></span>
      <a href="#"><em>3</em>Third Step</a>
      <span class="triangle"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="checkout-step4">
      <span class="triangle2"></span>
      <a href="#"><em>4</em>Fourth Step</a>
      <span class="triangle"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br><br>
```

Comment: I wish I could mark this as the answer, but after fiddling with it for a couple of hours, it just does not provide satisfactory results. Other pieces become out of alignment, and in the end, the out-line still shows in some of the elements.